# Gatsby prefetch request /page-data//page-data.json giving 404

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

[image: 404 request]

Not sure where is this double slash coming from, possibly something is missing between these 2 slashes..

Answer (score 1):

There must be a problem with paths in your `<Link to= .../>` because `Gatsby` makes requests to those pages when you hover the `<Link .../>` (Check `network` tab in devtools).
I've faced the same issue but resolved it by adding a helper function like this

```
import { join } from 'path';
import i18n from '../../i18n'; // I'm using i18n for internationalization

export const pathTo = (url: string): string => {
  const langPathPrefix: string = i18n.language === defaultLanguage ? '' : i18n.language;
  return join('/', langPathPrefix, url);
};
```

And my links changed this way:

```
<Link to={pathTo('path_to_your_page')}>
```

In your case there's probably a double-slashing in link to your homepage '/' so check that too.